# MongoDb. aggregation. Топ N записей для каждой страны, отсортированные по money

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

Дано

```
@Document()
public class UserData {
    @Id
    UUID _id;
    Long money;
    String country;
}
```

хочу из mongo достать топ 10 пользователей по money для каждой страны.

Агрегирую результат так

```
    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
            sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "money"),
            group("_id", "money", "country").
                    max("money").as("money"),
            limit(10)
    );
```

Но в итоге аггрегация возвращает результат обычной выборки.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: точно результат такой агрегации правильный?

Comment: результат такой агрегации не будет мапиться на исходный документ, потому что в результате агрегации в поле "_id" будет записано значение поля по которому группируются документы.

Comment: результат "казался" правильным, так как данных было не много. 
проблема была в том, что мапился _id на userUuid. у меня все заработало, после того, как я указал `@Id UUID _id`